# How to access browser X509 SAN attribute in AWS Lambda@Edge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-edge

I have scoured the AWS documentation but find no hint on how do this..

I'm new to Lambda@Edge and porting a legacy apache web server app to the platform.

In apache web server and nginx we have access to X509 cert attributes via environment variables,  AWS Lambda@Edge seems to have no 'like' capability.

Is there a way for a AWS Lambda function to access a browser's X509 attributes in the @Edge platform ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Lambda@Edge.

Comment: Is there a work around using IoT or other lambda configuration?

Comment: With IoT, [maybe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html).  I don't believe you can directly expose the certificate attributes, but client certs can be used with IoT.   It depends, I suspect, on exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  With Lambda's other companion service, API Gateway, this is not possible.  That service can use client certs only when it is acting as the client, proxying requests to an external back-end, and not when it is the server.

Comment: Talking to aws.. I'll let y'all know when I get an answer